# Iterate through an IEnumerable that uses yield

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, xunit

I have started unit testing my system and have a bunch of tests (using Xunit) taking the following TestData(), one vector at a time:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
   yield return new object[] { true, false };
   yield return new object[] { false, false };
   yield return new object[] { true, true };
   yield return new object[] { false, true };
}
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to (re)use the entire set within a same/single test.
For instance, here is a test I am trying to set up:

```
[Theory]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo()
{
    bool error = false;

    // The foreach does not work
    foreach (var a in TestData())
    {
        error |= doSomething(a[0], a[1]);
    }
            
    Assert.True(error != true, "doSomething() failed");
}
```

Note, in order to run one vector at a time, I previously used the following attributes:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
```

Maybe it is not possible because of the "yield". If not, how would you do that? Thanks.

Comment: `var list = TestData().ToList();`?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @sdgfsdh, I am not sure how to extract the data from "a"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an `IEnumerable<_>`, you might as well use proper types:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<bool, bool>> TestData()
{
   yield return new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, false);
   yield return new Tuple<bool, bool>(false, false);
   yield return new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true);
   yield return new Tuple<bool, bool>(false, true);
}

[Theory]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo()
{
    foreach (var a in TestData())
    {
        var error = doSomething(a.Item1, a.Item2);

        Assert.False(error, "doSomething() failed");
    }
}
```

If `object[]` is required then you will need to do some casting.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
   yield return new object[] { true, false };
   yield return new object[] { false, false };
   yield return new object[] { true, true };
   yield return new object[] { false, true };
}

[Theory]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo()
{
    foreach (var a in TestData())
    {
        var x = (bool) a[0];
        var y = (bool) a[1];

        var error = doSomething(x, y);

        Assert.False(error, "doSomething() failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it would be ideal, but [MemberData(nameof(TestData))] needs an object[], thanks

Comment: This simple, awesome! I thought the yield was being the issue. Thanks, exactly what I need :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want parameterized tests, you should use the InlineData attribute like so:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(true, false)]
[InlineData(false, false)]
[InlineData(true, true)]
[InlineData(false, true)]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo(bool value1, bool value2)
{      
    Assert.True(doSomething(value1, value2), "doSomething() failed");
}
```

See https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/

That article also explains how to work with the MemberData attribute to reuse test data.

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo(bool value1, bool value2)
{      
    Assert.True(doSomething(value1, value2), "doSomething() failed");
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
   yield return new object[] { true, false };
   yield return new object[] { false, false };
   yield return new object[] { true, true };
   yield return new object[] { false, true };
}
```

If you really want to use the TestData generator in [Fact] tests, you're on the right track, you just forgot to cast your objects back to booleans:

```
[Fact]
public void CanCheckAllInOneGo()
{
    varerror = false;

    foreach (var a in TestData())
    {
        error |= doSomething((bool)a[0], (bool)a[1]);
    }

    Assert.True(error != true, "doSomething() failed");
}
```

Comment: Thank, are you saying we cannot reuse TestData()? Using InlineData would be a duplication of my vectors

Comment: You can, by using the MemberData attribute. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using it in other tests, but in this test I want to use all the vectors simultaneously. I don't want 4 separate tests. So that is not what I need.

Comment: The point of the [Theory] attribute is to only write one test while the test runner treats it as 4 tests with separate parameters. If you don't it to show up as separate tests, use [Fact]. Also, you're implementation was pretty close, you just forgot to cast the objects back to bools. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tips. @sdgfsdh also pointed that out :-)